# how to do row wise comparison of string using NumPy of a single matrix

Tags: python, numpy

how to do row wise comparison of string using NumPy of a single matrix. where 1 row is compared with all other rows and subsequently 2 row is compared with all other rows, for comparison the column values are used like first row first column is compared with second row first column. This technique i should apply for multiple columns and wherever match is found i should update to the variable score by 1 and if no match and if there is missing field(like  nan) score should remain the same.

```
vector_col1 = np.array(data_list1)
for i in range(0,len(data_list1)-1):
    skill_score=0
    if ((data_list1[0] and data_list1[i+1])=='nan'):
        skill_score=0
    if (data_list1[0]==data_list1[i+1]):
        skill_score=skill_score+1
    vector_col1[i]=skill_score
print vector_col1
```

i expect the output to be 1 for matched score but actual output is 0